# Python: Run os.system for matching files

Tags: python, operating-system, wildcard, glob

I want to run one specific command for as often as there are matching files in my subdirs. Every file is named like this: sub-01_T1w, sub-02_T1w … . The command I’m trying to run looks like this: “bet   -F -m”.

*Edit* My Question: Every time I run the script none of the wildcards are replaced. The file paths are correct, but the os command is every time sub-[0-9][0-9] instead of: sub-01, sub-02, ... .

My first attempt looks like this:

```
import glob
import os

path = '/home/nico/Seminar/demo_fmri/'
subdirs = glob.glob('%s/sub-[0-9][0-9]'%(path))

for dir in subdirs:
   print dir  
   glob.glob(os.system("bet %s/anat/sub-[0-9][0-9]_T1w %s/anat/sub-[0-9][0-9]_T1w_brain -F -m"%(dir,dir)))
```

Comment: So... what's you question?

Comment: I cannot find a question here. Does your attempt work? If not, how does it fail? What does it do? Is there an error? What is it? I have more questions if you want... But it's probably best that you rewrite the question entirely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably misunderstood how `glob.glob` works. It compute a list of file paths depending on the pattern you gave as argument.

You should not pass to `glob.glob` the result of `os.system`, this is probably not what you want to do.

Try to solve your problem with something like this:

```
import glob
import os
import subprocess

path = '/home/nico/Seminar/demo_fmri/'
subdirs = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'sub-[0-9][0-9]'))

for dir in subdirs:
    print dir
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, 'anat/sub-[0-9][0-9]_T1w')):
        subprocess.call(['bet', file, file+'_brain', '-f', '-m'])
```

<s>Bonus: `%s` were removed in favor of `os.path.join` when needed. In addition, I used `str.format` in last line since I find it clearer. It's a question of style, do as you prefer</s>

Edit: replaced `os.system` by `subproces.call`, as [suggested by STD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476140/python-run-os-system-for-matching-files/45476590?noredirect=1#comment77913814_45476590)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @STD it's also best to avoid `os.system` and use `subprocess.call` instead - that way you don't have to worry about escaping arguments for the shell etc... so the above would be `subprocess.call(['bet', file, file+'_T1w_brain', '-f', '-m'])`